# Why element isn't hidden after changes of v-show attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p v-show="show">test</p>
      <button v-on:click="change">btn</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          show: true
        },
        methods: {
          change: function () {
            this.show = false;
            setTimeout("", 5000);
            this.show = true;
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does the element not hide for 5 seconds after pressing the button and then show again?
And how can I change the code to achieve this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directly sets `show` to `true`:

```js
console.log(false);
setTimeout(() => console.log("done"), 5000);
console.log(true);
```

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes a function to be executed after the timeout, this is where you need to change the variable:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { show: true },
  methods: {
    change: function () {
      this.show = false;
      setTimeout(() => this.show = true, 5000);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-show="show">test</p>
  <button v-on:click="change">btn</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` doesn't work like that.

It doesn't stop there, wait and continue after 5 seconds. It continues immediately to next step, so you immediately change `show` to true.

`setTimeout` calls it's callback asynchronously, meaning it will call the function you give it after 5 seconds.

So you need to do it like this:

`setTimeout(() => this.show = true, 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

Try running the toggle inside of the `setTimeout`

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  this.show = true;
}, 5000);
```